# Passing JSON to a PageMethod that expects a List<T> parameter

Tags: asp.net, json, pagemethods

I have an ASP.NET PageMethod with the following signature:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SaveCodes(ByVal codes As List(Of Code)) As String
```

I am trying to pass a JSON object to the PageMethod from the client side, but I get an error that the type String cannot be converted to type of List`<Code>`.

Here is the json that I'm building on the client and sending to the method:

{
    'codes' : {
        { "companyID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "customerType":"1", "code":"11    " },
        { "companyID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "customerType":"1", "code":"21    " }
    }
}

Here is my PageMethod call, (objects is the json string above):

```
PageMethods.SaveCodes(objects, successFn, errorFn);
```

I have been able to pass in simple data types and a single instance of the Code class, but I can't seem to find the magic to pass a List to the server method.  Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  The correct notation is listed below.  The main piece that was missing was the __type property for each object.  I had to dig around in a List that was returned from a PageMethod to find that.

```
{"codes":
[  
{"CompanyID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Code":"11    ","CustomerType":"1","__type":"Code"},
{"CompanyID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Code":"21    ","CustomerType":"1","__type":"Code"}
]
}
```

Comment: I did end up writing a blog post on this for a more detailed description:
http://www.brentman.com/blog/2010/01/15/asp-net-pagemethods-using-generic-lists

Comment: Thank you! for this and especially your blog post. Just saved me a ton of time.